# Laravel view load twice to display comment

Tags: laravel

I don't know why the page has to load twice to display comments.

Here is my route: `Route::post('/addComment', 'CommentsController@addComment');`

Here is my controller:

```
public function addComment(Request $request)
    {

       $this->validate($request, [
           'name' => 'required',
           'body' => 'required',
       ]);
        $lesson_id           = $request->lesson_id;
        $comment             = new Comment;
        $comment->name       = $request->input('name');
        $comment->body       = $request->input('body');
        $comment->parrent_id = '0';
        $comment->lesson_id  = $request->lesson_id;
        $comment->save();
        return back();
    }
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="leave_review">
              <h3 class="blog_heading_border"> コメント </h3>
              {!! Form::open(['action' => ['CommentsController@addComment'], 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'postForm' ]) !!}
                  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
                  <input type="hidden" id ="lesson_id" name="lesson_id" value="{{$lesson->id}}" /> 
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  @error('name')
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                  @enderror 
                  {{Form::label('name','名前')}}
                  {{Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-group', 'id' => 'name' ])  }}
                </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                @error('body')
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror 
                {{Form::label('body','メッセージ')}}
                {{Form::textarea('body', '', ['class' => 'form-group', 'id' => 'body'])  }}
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
              </div>
              </div>
              {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'send mt_btn_yellow pull-right', 'id' => 'submit'])}}
              {!! Form::close() !!}
              {{--  End add comment  --}}
             {{--Display comment--}} 
             <ol class="review-lists">
  
            @foreach ($comment as $value)
                <li class="comment">
                    <div class="activity_rounded">
                        <img src="/storage/icon/icon.jpg" alt="image"> </div>
                    <div class="comment-body">
                        <h4 class="text-left">{{$value->name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <small class="date-posted pull-right">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</small>
                        </h4>
                        <p>{{$value->body}} </p>
                        <button class="pull-left mt_btn_yellow" onclick="toggleReply('{{$value->id}}')">返事</button>
                        {{-- ENd Display comment--}}
```

Comment: where is @endforeach ?

Comment: Sorry to paste code not enough, but in my view have @endforeach below {{-- ENd Display comment--}}

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($comment as $value)
            <li class="comment">
                <div class="activity_rounded">
                    <img src="/storage/icon/icon.jpg" alt="image"> </div>
                <div class="comment-body">
                    <h4 class="text-left">{{$value->name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <small class="date-posted pull-right">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</small>
                    </h4>
                    <p>{{$value->body}} </p>
                    <button class="pull-left mt_btn_yellow" onclick="toggleReply('{{$value->id}}')">返事</button>
                    {{-- ENd Display comment--}}
```

you don't have a @endforeach

Comment: Sorry to paste code not enough, but in my view have @endforeach below {{-- ENd Display comment--}}